# ViewPager - setCurrentItem(int) does not slide

Tags: android

When I do a swipe action on a ViewPager the page slides, but if from a tab I do a viewPager.setCurrentItem(pageNum), it resets the page but does not slide.  How can I make the page slide programatically?

Comment: It should show the animation if sliding only one page. Otherwise, no animation is shown. Is this the behavior you're experiencing?

Comment: have you tried adding the smoothScroll boolean? viewPager.setCurrentItem(pageName,true)

Comment: Does not work. I am using android compatibility package 4.

Answer (score -1):

try

viewPager.setCurrentItem(item, true);